# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

In my foreach, I see the following error:

**Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array** [..] **on line 97**

```
 88.    foreach ($response as $result) {
 89.        if($result['provider'] == 'Facebook') {
 90.            $provider = 'facebook';
 91.        }else{
 92.            $provider = 'twitter';
 93.        }
 94.        $user = array(
 95.            'provider' => $result['provider'],
 96.            'id' => $result['uid'],
 97.            'name' => $result['info']['name'],
 98.            'image' => $result['info']['image'],
 99.            'link' => $result['info']['urls'][$provider],
100.        );
101.        echo "<h1>".$user['provider']."</h1>";
102.        echo "<p>".$user['id']."</p>";
103.        echo '<p><img src="'.$user['image'].'" /></p>';
105.        echo "<p>".$user['name']."</p>";
106.        echo "<p>".$user['link']."</p>";
107.    }
```

I've tried reading around the web to understand what the problem is but it seems that some issues are unrelated to mine. I should also just come out with it and let you know I'm not that great with PHP. Can someone lend a hand?

**P.S. I added `break;` after the last echo and that solved it but I don't think that's the way to go about it.**

Comment: what is the output of var_dump($response); or var_dump($result['provider']);

Comment: Do a var_dump of `$result['info']`. Probably doesn't contain what the code suggests it should.

Comment: @rccoros var_dump($result['provider'] returns string(1) "2". That's weird.

Comment: it mean's that $response is string not array

Comment: @sanjeev is_array($response); returns true.

Comment: How about is_array($result['provider']); what does it return?

Comment: @rccoros That also returns true.

Comment: @rccoros Actually. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: So you have to check if your $response does have the content you wanted. Do a var_dump($response);

Comment: @rccoros It does. See here: http://cloud.chrisburton.me/TPoM

Comment: it seems that you don't have subarray($result['info']['name']) of $result['info'] when you are trying to assign it. you should vardump array data first

Comment: Chris you said that var_dump($result['info']) returns a string type, but is_array($result['info']) returns true. Where did you put the two checks? I mean you should put both before you initialize the $user variable.

Comment: @AwladLiton $result['info'] looks like this: http://cloud.chrisburton.me/TQZC

Comment: @AntonioE. See above comment screenshot. And yes I did put those in the wrong place. If I put it above the $user variable, is_array  returns true and var_dump spits out as it should with the correct values.

Comment: even is_array($result['info']) is put before $user = array(... ?

Comment: @AntonioE. Correct. This is the result of both put before $user = array(.. http://cloud.chrisburton.me/TQXF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used `$result['info']` in a loop. it should be sometimes sub array of `$result['info']` is not set.
It seems that you do not need to run loop. because you will have single user info at a time.
or you can use break like this:

```
foreach ($response as $result) {
    $provider = strtolower($result['provider']);
    $user = array(
        'provider' => $result['provider'],
        'id' => $result['uid'],
        'name' => isset($result['info']['name']) ? $result['info']['name'] : '',
        'image' => isset($result['info']['image']) ? $result['info']['image'] : '',
        'link' => isset($result['info']['urls'][$provider]) ? $result['info']['urls'][$provider] : ''
    );
print_r($user);
    echo "<h1>" . $user['provider'] . "</h1>";
    echo "<p>" . $user['id'] . "</p>";
    echo '<p><img src="' . $user['image'] . '" /></p>';
    echo "<p>" . $user['name'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>" . $user['link'] . "</p>";
    break;
}
```

Comment: @Chris Burton : i have updated my answer. can you try this now?

Comment: @Chris Burton : can you just remove this line and test if it worked then i will try differently

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45448/discussion-between-awlad-liton-and-chris-burton)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the problem was the foreach loop. Adding `break;` after the last echo **or** simply removing the foreach and using `$result = $response['auth'];` work equally.

Answer (score 1):

`$result['info']` is obviously a string and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You declare $result['info'] as a string somewhere then later try to use it as an array. Try to  var_dump $result['info'].